# como hago para que no aparezcan los valores repetidos por php

Tags: php, array

Mi codigo es el siguiente, pero solo me muestra los valores no repetidos del primer array

```
<?php 
function paisesU(array $array1, array $array2) : array
{
    $repetir1 = array_unique($array1);
    $repetir2 = array_unique($array2); 

    $resultado = $repetir1 + $repetir2 ;
    
    return $resultado;
   
}

$paises= paisesU(['Mexico', 'Brasil', 'Portugal', 'Brasil'], ['Brasil', 'Inglaterra', 'Brasil']);
echo join(', ', $paises);
```

pero no intento hacer que me muestro sin repetir los paises, por ejemplo que me muestre mexico, brasil, portugal e Inglaterra y no me muestre repetidos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

intenta probar uniendo los 2 arreglos y luego le pasas array_unique al resultado.

```
function paisesU(array $array1, array $array2)
{
    $resultado = array_merge($array1, $array2);
    $resultado = array_unique($resultado);
    return $resultado;
}

$paises= paisesU(['Mexico', 'Brasil', 'Portugal', 'Brasil'], ['Brasil', 'Inglaterra', 'Brasil']);
echo join(', ', $paises);
```

Comment: Gracias, lo hice como mencionaste y si da el resultado correcto